# Laravel handle default route if optional parameter is not in the list

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I define optional parameter "type" in the route and limit acceptable values (A,B or C) with where clause:

```
Route::get('test/{type?}', ['uses' => 'MyController@index'])->where('type', 'A|B|C');
```

If type value is different to A,B or C (e.g. "X") framework returns error page:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php
```

In such case I would like to ignore received optional parameter and handle route as it is with no specified parameter i.e.: `test/`

How can it be implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By allowing values for the type parameter that are not in the regex condition, means the `where` method is useless in this case. However you can move the logic to a middleware and handle it there. Here are the steps:

**1.** Create a new middleware, let's call it `OptionalType`, by running this command in your Laravel directory:

```
php artisan make:middleware OptionalType
```

**2.** The previous command created a file in `app/Http/Middleware` named `OptionalType.php`. The content of that file should be the following:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class OptionalType
{
    protected $allowedTypes = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $route = $request->route();

        // If the `type` parameter value is not within the allowed list
        // set the value to `null` which is as if it was not passed
        if (!in_array($route->parameter('type'), $this->allowedTypes)) {
            $route->setParameter('type', null);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**3.** Next you need to register the middleware as a route middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'type' => \App\Http\Middleware\OptionalType::class,
];
```

**4.** Now you can add the middleware to your route (the `where` condition is not needed anymore because the logic is in the middleware now):

```
Route::get('test/{type?}', ['middleware' => 'type', 'uses' => 'MyController@index']);
```

Now when you pass anything other than `A`, `B` or `C` to the route, the parameter will become `null` as if it wasn't even passed.

---

You can read more about middleware in the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware).